# Turing Machine halts for at least $1024$ strings as input

Tags: computer-science, computability

Consider the language $$L = \{\text{"}M\text{"} \mid \text{Turing Machine } M \text{ halts for at least }1024\text{ input-strings}\}.$$

Is L a recursively enumerable language?

My answer is no based on the definition of a recursively enumerable language. But is it so simple? Any "better"(and mathematical) way to prove it?

Answer (score 2):

"Based on the definition of a recursively enumerable language" isn't a proof - **why** do you think that the answer is no?

In fact, the answer is *yes* - we can indeed recursively enumerate all the codes for machines which halt on at least $1024$-many strings. Do you see how to do this? (HINT: First see why we can enumerate the codes for machines which halt on at least *one* string, then generalize.)

---

As a further hint, the "at least" here is crucial: the set of codes for machines which halt on *exactly* $1024$-many strings is *not* r.e.

Comment: if two TM produce the same output (or both don't halt) for each input, do you consider they are the same, or do you look at their code ?

Comment: @user1952009 I don't see how this is related to the question.

Comment: Two turing machines are the same only if they are exactly the same. @user1952009 Otherwise, it isn't possible to encode them as integers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : you mean if there have the same source code. hence I'm not sure how to enumerate all the TM halting for a given input.

Comment: @user1952009 Are you referring to the set $\{"M": M(\sigma)$ halts$\}$ for some fixed string $\sigma$? (Note that the problem isn't about this.) If so, this is a standard exercise: at stage $2^m3^n$, run the $m$th Turing machine on input $\sigma$ for $n$-many steps. If it halts, throw $m$ into your set; if it doesn't, keep $m$ out of your set for now. Note that the question of telling whether two machines are the same never comes up - we're not asking for an *injective* enumeration of machines, we want *all the codes*!

Comment: Ι'm having a mental blackout. I don't think I can think this through.

Comment: @L.In Alright, let's look at an easier example - the one I mention, $X=\{"M": M(\sigma)$ halts for *some* $\sigma\}$. We want to show this is r.e. **Formally**, this means that we want to find some partial computable $f$ such that $dom(f)=X$, but this is a bit abstract. **Informally**, we want to argue that there's some way - given a machine $M$ - to eventually notice if $M$ halts on some input. Think of it as a game: I give you a machine $M$, you get to play around with it forever, and if $M$ halts on some input, you eventually have to say "Yes, $M$ is in $X$". Does this help?

Comment: Another way to rephrase it: a set $A$ is r.e. if, for any $n\in A$, there's a way for you to *convince me* that $n$ is in $A$ in a finite amount of time. Suppose $M$ halts on some input. How can you convince me of this?

Comment: Is it enough for %any n% or %every n% is needed?
Well, the problem is a bit abstract, we would have to go over the elements of A or check how it is defined.

Comment: @L.In For *every* $n$. That is: for each $n\in A$, there has to be a way for you to convince me - in finite time - that $n$ is in fact in $A$. Do you see how to do this for the $X$ I defined above?

Comment: Ι'll have to admit it's not very clear :S

Comment: Alright, turn it around: if I claimed to you "This machine halts on some input," how could I convince you? For example: if I claimed "This machine halts on input $1$," clearly the way I would convince you is tell you how many steps it takes to halt. Then you could check this by running the machine on input $1$ for that many steps. $(i)$ Does this make sense? $(ii)$ Based on this, how would I convince you that $M$ halts on *some* input?

Comment: In the same way, you would tell me that machine $M$ halts for some input(we already know it halts for at least $1024$ strings), the amount of steps required and then I would use it(the machine $M$) to verify your statement.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely r.e.

At step $\langle M,n,k\rangle$ enumerate $M$ if Turing machine $M$ halts in $n$ steps for $1024$ inputs less than $k$.

Then any $M$ which halts for at least 1024 inputs will be enumerated.